# Excel Pivot Table: Can I analyze two columns of data as if they were a single column?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table to track trades of portions of shifts.  They are recorded by date as data pairs, with one person getting a positive credit and the other a negative credit.

```
Column
1 - Date
2 - Name
3 - Hours (Positive)
4 - Name
5 - Hours (Negative)
```

I want a Pivot Table that has a single list of employees and a number that shows their Net Balance for the time period covered.

I tried to insert a Field (Field1) in the Pivot Table as a Calculated field of Hours (Negative Hours) and Hours2 (Positive Hours). But it treats the Carlos in the negative hours as a different person from Carlos with positive hours rather than creating a sum of Carlos' net hours.

***Basic Data***
[image: Basic Data]

***Expected Result***
[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the table and then create your table, especially if you have `365`.

In `365` I named the data table `Shifts` and you can use this formula to unpivot the data. It will adapt to any number of `Person-Hours` paired columns:

```
=LET(
    persCols, SEQUENCE(, (COLUMNS(Shifts) - 1) / 2, 2, 2),
    hrsCols, SEQUENCE(, (COLUMNS(Shifts) - 1) / 2, 3, 2),
    persons, TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(Shifts, persCols)),
    hrs, TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(Shifts, hrsCols)),
    VSTACK({"Person", "Hours"}, HSTACK(persons, hrs))
)
```

This results in a table:
[image]

And you can use the regular Excel pivot table wizard to create the result table in your desired format:
[image]

However, this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac).

This solution will work also for any number of Person-Hour paired columns.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next lines to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Shifts"]}[Content],


//can have multiple person-hour pairs after the first "Date" column
    personCols = List.Alternate(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1),1,1,1),
    hoursCols = List.Alternate(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1),1,1,0),
    typeSets = {{"Date", type date}} & List.Transform(personCols, each {_, type text}) & List.Transform(hoursCols, each {_, type number}),

//Set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, typeSets),

//Unpivot the data columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Remove now uneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Date", "Attribute"}),

//add a "shifted" column to facilitate matching the person with their hours
    #"Add Shifted Values" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Removed Columns") &
        {List.RemoveFirstN(#"Removed Columns"[Value],1) & {null}},
        type table[Person=text, Hours=number]),

//Remove unneeded rows
    #"Removed Alternate Rows" = Table.AlternateRows(#"Add Shifted Values",1,1,1),

//Group by Person and SUM the hours for each
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Alternate Rows", {"Person"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([Hours]), type number}}),

//Sort result in alphabetical order
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Person", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much.  Can I use that formula in a regular cell in Excel 365?  Do I need to use a table?  I'm much more familiar with Column letters.  I haven't learned anything since Pivot Tables were introduced 20 yrs ago, LOL.

Comment: @user1191513 I've not seen that term. What is a *regular cell*?  How does it differ from one that is not *regular*? What happened when you tried the formula?

Comment: Yes! It is great!  Sorry about my unclear question, I wasn't sure if that first response was a formula for an Excel spreadsheet or if it was to be used in a Power-something file.

Comment: @user1191513 **Formula** means formula to be placed in a worksheet cell. **M Code** is the codeing language used in Power Query.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `persCols, SEQUENCE(, (COLUMNS(Shifts) - 1) / 2, 2, 2)` instead of the simpler `persCols, COLUMNS(Shifts(2,4)`?  I also would like to repeat the date so that the array can be filtered by date, so wrote this with date, month and year in Col 1, 2, 3, then names in 4, 6 and hours in 5, 7. `=HSTACK(TEXT(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(ShiftShifts,1,1),1,),"mm/dd/yyyy"),TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(ShiftShifts,2,2),1,),TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(ShiftShifts,3,3),1,),TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(ShiftShifts,4,6),1,),TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(ShiftShifts,5,7),1,))`

Comment: `persCols, SEQUENCE(, (COLUMNS(Shifts) - 1) / 2, 2, 2)` So the formula can adapt in case you might have more than two `Person / Hour` pairs of columns.